# How to add catalog price rule to have different discounts for different categories?

Tags: catalog-price-rules

I am new to magento . I want to add catalog price rule to have different discounts for different categories . Currently i can select one or multiple categories from conditions tab and then enter discount amount but that will be only for those specific categories and for rest there will be no discount .

I found out that on adding catalog rule it calculates and saves all product prices under selected category to 'catalogrule_product_price' table .

I want to have discount say 15% for category id 4 and 20% for rest . How can i achieve that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right you want to have 2 different discounts

Products of specific categories

**First Rule**

***CONDITIONS***

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND in the cart with ANY of these conditions true:

  Category is one of [comma,delimited,list,of,category,IDs] 4
```

***ACTIONS***

```
Set “Apply” to “Percent of product price discount”
Set “Discount Amount” to “15”
```

**Second rule**

***CONDITIONS***

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND in the cart with ANY of these conditions true:

  Category is one of [comma,delimited,list,of,category,IDs] all other IDS in
```

here

***ACTIONS***

```
Set “Apply” to “Percent of product price discount”
Set “Discount Amount” to “20”
```

Comment: i was looking for two different discounts in one rule , but this will work for me . thanks